# MySQL: "`myTbl`.`foo` = foo" evaluates to true. How do I prevent that?

Tags: mysql, configuration

say I had a stored proc like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_id INT; 
    SET user_id = 1; 
    SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = user_id;
END
```

and a table like this:

```
users
=============================
user_id  |  user_displayname
-----------------------------
1        |  Joe
2        |  Steve
3        |  Brad
```

Calling the stored proc above gives me:

```
1  |  Joe
2  |  Steve
3  |  Brad
```

Is there something I can add to `my.cnf` that tells MySQL to be very strict about punctuation?

I'm used to being in java land and being able to do:

```
int userId = 1;
if(aUserObject.userId == userId)
    //do something
```

Comment: If there were, you might not want to use it -- someone reading your code won't expect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SET @user_id := 1; 
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = @user_id;
```

Comment: cool! Thanks! 2 questions about that. 1) what's the difference between SET [at]user_id = 1; and SET [at]user_id := 1? := vs =
/// 2) will the @ make the variable persist outside of the scope of the stored proc, or no? I haven't read up on my session variables in a while.

Comment: I found the answer to my first question here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html /// Still reading there for the answer to my second question.

Comment: would I not DECLARE @user_id anymore since user variables/session variables aren't "strong-ish" typed?

Comment: @MicronXD: yep, I think `DECLARE` is not necessary there then